# Zlib nodejs Error: invalid stored block lengths

Tags: c, node.js, zlib

I'm trying to send some compressed data over the network, I think the data is successfully compressed since I can re-inflate it from the code that deflates the data (written in C), however when the data arrives at my server (nodejs using express) and tries to inflate the data I'm receiving:

```
{ Error: invalid stored block lengths
    at InflateRaw.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15) errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

Any Help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Szz.

P.D: I can provide code snipped if it is useful for anyone.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the quick answer and sorry for the delay, I've been working in my code, now I'm sending the original data to the server along with the compressed data. When the original data arrives the server I'm deflating it in order to see the buffers generated, surprisingly the buffers of the compressed data sent over the network and the buffer compressed in the server are the same **except for the two first bytes** particulary:

```
<Buffer 78 da 15 8c c9 11 00 41 08 02 ff c6 82 55 83 b7 f9 27 b6 ee 13 68 7a a6 b0 4c b8 a7 68 ac 81 61 84 5a 8b e6 82 6b 05 bd aa 44 d9 5e a0 d7 20 6c 2f a6 ... >

<Buffer 15 8c c9 11 00 41 08 02 ff c6 82 55 83 b7 f9 27 b6 ee 13 68 7a a6 b0 4c b8 a7 68 ac 81 61 84 5a 8b e6 82 6b 05 bd aa 44 d9 5e a0 d7 20 6c 2f a6 bf 9b ... >
```

So, I think my question now is can I assume that this first two bytes will always appear in the compressed data from the C program? Is there any option to avoid this first two bytes? Am I doing well?

Here I leave you the function that compress the data in the C part, the node part is just formidable parsing the post input and a little work with buffers now.

```
int compress_image (compressed_image raw, size_t size, compressed_image * out) {

    z_stream strm;
    int out_size = 0;

    *out = (compressed_image) malloc(size);

    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;

    int ret = deflateInit(&strm, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION); /* Max compression level, but bad speed performace */

    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return ret;

    strm.avail_in = size;
    strm.next_in = (unsigned char *)raw;

    do {

        strm.avail_out = size;
        strm.next_out = *out;
        ret = deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);    /* no bad return value */
        assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */
        out_size += (size - strm.avail_out);

    } while (strm.avail_out == 0);

    (void)deflateEnd(&strm);

    return out_size;
}
```

Thanks again!

**EDIT 2:**
I'm dumping my buffers now and I can see some trailing bytes that differs too,
here you have the buffer coming from C program:

```
00000000: 78da 158c c911 0041 0802 ffc6 8255 83b7  xÚ..É..A..ÿÆ.U.·
00000010: f927 b6ee 1368 7aa6 b04c b8a7 68ac 8161  ù'¶î.hz¦°L¸§h¬.a
00000020: 845a 8be6 826b 05bd aa44 d95e a0d7 206c  .Z.æ.k.½ªDÙ^.× l
00000030: 2fa6 bf9b 680e f2ce 9c67 975f 0e58 2d91  /¦¿.h.òÎ.g._.X-.
00000040: 75dc f1ed b25c 687a 43dd 42bc 1f98 e7dd  uÜñí²\hzCÝB¼..çÝ
00000050: 79a7 99f6 5fd3 bfcc 86f2 01b0 f51a cd    y§.ö_Ó¿Ì.ò.°õ.Í
```

And the buffer deflated in the server:

```
00000000: 158c c911 0041 0802 ffc6 8255 83b7 f927  ..É..A..ÿÆ.U.·ù'
00000010: b6ee 1368 7aa6 b04c b8a7 68ac 8161 845a  ¶î.hz¦°L¸§h¬.a.Z
00000020: 8be6 826b 05bd aa44 d95e a0d7 206c 2fa6  .æ.k.½ªDÙ^.× l/¦
00000030: bf9b 680e f2ce 9c67 975f 0e58 2d91 75dc  ¿.h.òÎ.g._.X-.uÜ
00000040: f1ed b25c 687a 43dd 42bc 1f98 e7dd 79a7  ñí²\hzCÝB¼..çÝy§
00000050: 99f6 5fd3 bfcc 86f2 01
```

However creating a new buffer without the first two bytes I'm able to se my data properly inflated in the server:

my node.js part:

```
const dump = require('buffer-hexdump');

router.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {

    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = "./uploads"

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

        let deflated = zlib.deflateRawSync(fs.readFileSync(files.image_raw.path));

        let image_buff = fs.readFileSync(files.image.path);
        let buff = Buffer.alloc(image_buff.length - 2);

        image_buff.copy(buff, 0, 2);

        console.log(buff.equals(deflated)); //false
        console.log(dump(deflated));
        console.log(dump(image_buff));

        zlib.inflateRaw(buff, (err, buffer) => {

            if (err)
                console.error(err);
            else
                console.log(buffer.toString()); //here I can see my data!!

        });

        res.status(200).send("POST received!");

    });
});
```

I don't think it is solved however ...

Thanks again!

Szz.

Comment: Can you please share your node.js code so we can see how you are inflating the request?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide your code, as well as the code you are using in C to decompress. It would also help to see the first several bytes of example data, to see if there is a zlib header, a gzip header, or no header on the deflate data.

Comment: Hey; I guess this is the normal behavior in both node and C parts?